# Responsive Design: Allow user to also view Full Site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When using responsive design, is there a way to still allow a user to view the full site?

E.g. They are viewing on an iPhone, but want to see the full site.  They click a "Full Site" link, and it shows them the 1024px version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using media queries, only apply rules beneath a body element having the class 'responsive'.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body.responsive {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

If the user doesn't want to view the responsive layout, simply remove the 'responsive' class from the body element, nullifying all rules. You could persist the users preference by cookie or some other method as well.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/obaquq/edit#javascript,html

Reducing the window to no more than 500px will turn the text white, and the background blue. This is conditional on the body having the 'responsive' class. Clicking the first paragraph will toggle this class, and thus toggle the effects of the media query itself.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. So, are you saying that I should use something like jQuery to see if it is a mobile device, then add the responsive class? Or do it another way?

Comment: @NicHubbard I would start by default with a responsive site, meaning, load the `responsive` class on the body by default. People opt-out of the responsive experience.

Comment: @NicHubbard Then use your media query to only show the "Full Site" link on  smaller screens, the link removes the `responsive` class

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering about this. I had success using jQuery to modify the viewport tag, seems to work fairly well from what I can tell so far. Doesn't require multiple stylesheets or a lot of extra CSS.

http://creativeandcode.com/responsive-view-full-site/

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this, but thought about this issue myself. I imagine you could use a stylesheet switcher that deactivates the core responsive stylesheet, leaving the user with the full version

Switching stylesheets certainly isn't a new concept. Here is an article for ALA circa 2001 addressing switching stylesheets: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/